# could not load any Objective-C class information: bundle Identifier and Path are nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am currently using Realm for storing local data and suddenly my app is crashing with the error:
could not load any Objective-C class information and this will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

I tried searching answers and many suggested to delete and re run the app or re run the Xcode but I am still stuck.

App is currently crashing on loading and returns nil for path and bundle Identifier. Below is the line where it hits:

```
NSString *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
```

With Error:  Thread 1: Exc_bad_access

Please if someone can help me with this it will be really good. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you've shared about the Objective-C runtime failing to load classes, you may be experiencing the [SR-1055](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1055) Swift bug, which was [recently fixed in Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/1914).

If you reorder your fields so that a non-empty type is the first declared stored property, it will work around the issue.

This bug & workarounds are further documented in several places:

- This blog post by Caesar Wirth: http://cjwirth.com/2016/03/26/xcode-7-3-crashing/
- This GitHub issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3383